# How to iterate through a list of users using Tweepy and Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api, twitterapi-python

In the first part of my code, I'm obtaining a list of 20 users who have used the word 'gym' in a Tweet. This part is working fine.

In the second part, I'm trying to use the usernames obtained in the first part, and get each of their most recent 20 tweets.

The code I have currently isn't running with any errors, however it definitely isn't returning 20 Tweets of each of the people I obtained in the first part, all it does is return the very last row from the result in the first part.

My code is below, as you can see I've tried to use the list I created in the first part 'tweets', as the id input in the second part, and I've used [2] as an attempt to only call the 3rd column of the list (where the usernames are).

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import pandas as pd

access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

tweets = []

count = 20

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="gym"+'-filter:retweets', since='2020-02-08', tweet_mode='extended',
                           lang='en').items(count):

    try:
        data = [tweet.full_text, tweet.user.screen_name]
        data = tuple(data)
        tweets.append(data)

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
        continue

    except StopIteration:
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(tweets,
                  columns=['Tweet', '@ Name'])

print(df)

new_tweets = []

username = tweets[1]
count = 20

for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=username, tweet_mode='extended').items(count):

    try:
        data = [tweet.full_text, tweet.user.screen_name]
        data = tuple(data)
        new_tweets.append(data)

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
        continue

    except StopIteration:
        break

df2 = pd.DataFrame(new_tweets, columns=['Tweets', '@ Name'])

print(df2)

df2.to_csv('test3.csv')
```

And this is my output:

```
                                                Tweet          @ Name
0            Gym chronicles                             chocodilish
1   @neilmcrowther @SpotifyUK I have a Spotify pla...    carey_bamber
2   Food pick-up for virtual learners today 9:00-1...    allentrotter
3                         couldn’t sleep so gym it is   esmeraldahdz_
4   We need I.D. to buy beer, to buy ciggies, we n...       beryl1946
5   So I actually have to go to the gym to have a ...       ___tshego
6   Currently three Marcela Bielsa lookalikes in t...     sammyptweet
7   I’m dreading going to the gym and coming back ...   cinnamonKayyy
8   yes we were there... what the fuck is going on...        blubbsie
9   @IamEzeNwanyi @LilburnEnugu @mr_robmichael @He...        _lilivet
10                                   GYM WEEK 2  LEGO        Mondo_92
11  Webinars for this week are as follows,\nBrain ...    EdCentreMayo
12    I rather be wakin up for the gym than work tbh.    illmindofPAT
13  First day back in the gym doing BASKETBALL  ...  AUMWarhawksWBB
14  i don’t wanna go to school today since i know ...  CEOofTsuyuAsui
15  @sunikies GYM DHSHSKDSH (i miss it :( ), indiv...       shienIove
16  @PaulMumba_ Is that gym work I'm seeing on tha...       jaymaxgie
17  Body builders on Instagram don’t go to the gym...  OfficialShann_
18                      @DivinePooh gym and game room     FinesseDee2
19  I use to wake up to go to the gym at this hour...    missgenafire
20
                                              Tweets        @ Name
0  I use to wake up to go to the gym at this hour...  missgenafire

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help at all would be appreciated, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop, you are still using the *tweet* variable of your first for loop. You should use the *user* variable.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. You ar enot iterateing over the 20 different usernames. You hard coded it to use only 1 `username = tweets[1]`. Even then, that's a tuple of `('tweetmessage','username')`, so you'd want the string in index position 1 there, Ie `'tweets[1][1]`
2. You're iterating sotring as `user`, but then calling on the `tweet` variable:

   ```
    for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=username, tweet_mode='extended').items(count):

        try:
            data = [user.full_text, user.user.screen_name]  #<-- correct
            #data = [tweet.full_text, tweet.user.screen_name]  #<-- incorrect
            ...
   ```

**Full Code:**

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import pandas as pd

access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

tweets = []

count = 20

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="gym"+'-filter:retweets', since='2020-02-08', tweet_mode='extended',
                           lang='en').items(count):

    try:
        data = [tweet.full_text, tweet.user.screen_name]
        data = tuple(data)
        tweets.append(data)

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
        continue

    except StopIteration:
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(tweets,
                  columns=['Tweet', '@ Name'])

print(df)

new_tweets = []
count = 20
for tweet, username in tweets:
    for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=username, tweet_mode='extended').items(count):
    
        try:
            data = [user.full_text, user.user.screen_name]
            data = tuple(data)
            new_tweets.append(data)
    
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
            continue
    
        except StopIteration:
            break

df2 = pd.DataFrame(new_tweets, columns=['Tweets', '@ Name'])

print(df2)

df2.to_csv('test3.csv')
```